# Make UIViewController the delegate of UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController in which I am having a UITableView and in the tableViewCell I am having a collectionView. How can I make my ViewController to be the delegate of CollectionView to align myself with the MVC architecture ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you share some code?

Comment: what do you want to do with the delegate?

Comment: as per my understanding, I think you want when you perform an action in collectionView you want changes to happen in UIviewController with use of Delegates ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Yes. I want to handle the CollectionView cell tap in my View Controller rather than in my TableViewCell.

Comment: @BagusCahyono I have currently made UITableViewCell as the delegate of CollectionView since my collectionView is inside a tableviewcell. Though I know this is not the right way hence seeking a better solution. I want to handle the collectionView cell tap in my View Controller .

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I want to handle the collectionView cell selection on my viewController.

Comment: make two protocols , One will take control from collectionView to TableView and second from Table to VC , But as you did Mentioned View hierarchy its ViewController-->TableView-->CollectionView all will be in same window so you can also directly link collectionView to VC

Comment: you can make a protocol, then confirm that protocol with the viewController, now pass the address of the viewController to the tableViewCell and then pass it to the collectionView, now you can use that delegate and do what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` set `cell.yourCollectionView.delegate = yourViewController`, and in ViewController implement methods of delegate